# I can access variables in a class but calling method throws NoClassDefFoundError?

Tags: java

I've been consistently getting a NoClassDefFoundError that I can't understand. 
I have a class which is clearly there since I can access variables defined in that class. I have verified that the class exists but when I attempt to call the function I need, I get a NoClassDefFoundError. Here is the log of the error I'm getting:

```
[INFO_|08/04 08:18:41|MaintenanceCronReport.main:375] Testing :Test Variable
[ERROR|08/04 08:18:41|Cron$CronJob.run:1423] Exception: [CronMaintenance_1min] org.opengts.scheduler.MaintenanceCronReport.main: -account=ALL -db.sql.provider=mysql -db.sql.host=localhost -db.sql.port=3306 -db.sql.dbname=test -db.sql.user=test -db.sql.password=test -smtp.host=smtp.gmail.com -smtp.port=25 -smtp.user=test@test.com -smtp.user.emailAddress=test@test.com -smtp.password= -smtp.enableSSL=true -sendMail=true -saveOnHD=false -pathToTMP=C:\tmp\ -pathToGTS=C:\Users\User\workspace\GTS\ -emailTo=test@test.com -log.include.date=true [*/1 * * * *] {thread}
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/opengts/war/report/ReportFactory
    at org.opengts.scheduler.MaintenanceCronReport.main(MaintenanceCronReport.java:376)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.opengts.util.MethodAction.invoke(MethodAction.java:389)
    at org.opengts.util.MethodAction.invoke(MethodAction.java:372)
    at org.opengts.extra.util.Cron$CronJob.run(Cron.java:1420)
    at org.opengts.util.ThreadPool$ThreadJob.run(ThreadPool.java:650)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.opengts.war.report.ReportFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 9 more
[INFO_|08/04 08:18:41|Cron$CronJob.run:1426] CronEnd  : [CronMaintenance_1min] org.opengts.scheduler.MaintenanceCronReport.main: -account=ALL -db.sql.provider=mysql -db.sql.host=localhost -db.sql.port=3306 -db.sql.dbname=test -db.sql.user=test -db.sql.password=test -smtp.host=smtp.gmail.com -smtp.port=25 -smtp.user=test@test.com -smtp.user.emailAddress=test@test.com -smtp.password= -smtp.enableSSL=true -sendMail=true -saveOnHD=false -pathToTMP=C:\tmp\ -pathToGTS=C:\Users\User\workspace\GTS\ -emailTo=test@test.com -log.include.date=true [*/1 * * * *] {thread}
```

The complete code is too long to put here so I hope that this section will do. Here I can access the variable TEST_VARIABLE just fine but attempting to call the static method test on the next line throws the error shown above.

```
Print.logInfo("Testing :" +ReportFactory.TEST_VARIABLE);
Print.logInfo(ReportFactory.test());
```

The variable TEST_VARIABLE and the method test are just simply defined as:

```
public static final String TEST_VARIABLE= "Test Variable";
public static String test()
{
    return "TEST METHOD RETURN";
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Just a guess, but perhaps you need a specific constructor or implements that you haven't provided?

Comment: If the code compiles in your IDE but gives a `ClassNotFoundException` during execution then perhaps there's something wrong with your execution environment (cron?). This typically means you're missing a library off your `CLASSPATH` or something like that.

Comment: I wouldn't count on `ReportFactory.TEST_VARIABLE` actually trying to access the `ReportFactory` class.  It's a constant string, so the compiler may be able to simply pull the string out of the pool.  Try removing the `final` from the `TEST_VARIABLE` declaration and see if it still accesses the variable.

Comment: Thanks for your replies guys. I'll try what was suggested and make sure of all libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [JLS §12.4.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1).  It says, in part:

> A class or interface type T will be initialized immediately before the
>   first occurrence of any one of the following: .....
>
> A static field declared by T is used and the field is not a constant
>   variable (§4.12.4).

Note that this means that if a field is *not* a constant variable, the class will be initialized before the field is first accessed.  But this doesn't apply if the field *is* a constant variable, as it is in your case.  Thus, the call to `ReportFactory.test()` is likely the first class access to which §12.4.1 applies.  That doesn't explain why you're getting the exception (you'll need to check your classpath, for starters), but it should help explain why it's possible for this exception to occur after `TEST_VARIABLE` is successfully accessed.

Comment: Thanks ajb. Yes that explains why removing the final keyword from TEST_VARIABLE causes the error to occur at that line. I'm checking the classpath now to find the cause of the error.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have complete dependencies in your classpath make sure to put all the required jars in your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

My issue has been resolved. As expected, it turns out that I was missing required jar files from my class path. Thanks to all who replied. I appreciate it.